# How to include/import a c++ app in VB.net

Tags: c++, vb.net, import

Link grammar is a piece of software allowing for sentence parsing. It has an API that I hope to use ([Details here](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/api/index.html#cons)) however the example is written in c++ and I'm a vb.net user. I've tried adding a reference to the file named:

```
link-includes.h
```

But vs2010 doesn't allow me to select this file since it's not one of the recognised file types for a reference. I've tried adding the above file to the solution but that doesn't allow me to reference it in any way (as far as I know). Any advice/hints/suggestions would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VB.Net project can't directly reference a C++ header file. In order to use C++ code from VB.Net, **one** of the following approaches will need to be used:

1. Compile the C++ code to a native DLL, which the VB.Net code can then [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
2. Compile the C++ code to a native DLL, which is then [exposed via COM](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/Step-by-Step-COM-Tutorial.htm)
3. Compile the C++ code in a [C++/CLI project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx), which the VB.Net project can reference as another managed project (i.e., via project References)

Additional information can be found here: [Invoke Native C++ DLL from .NET Code](http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Invoke%20Native%20C%2b%2b%20DLL%20from%20.NET)